# Crear menú inferior compatible con todas las densidades de pantalla

Tags: android, xml

Tengo el siguiente menú en código xml, todos los botones están con su constraint superior, inferior y anclados a la izquierda. También he probado con un linearlayout horizontal pero el resultado no es del todo óptimo, ya que en móviles con pantalla de baja densidad los botones se salen por fuera de la pantalla :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/consumosButton"
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:contentDescription="@string/CalculateConsumption"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_icons_consumo_32px"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/mConsumos"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:tint="@color/black"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:contentDescription="@string/SearchMechanic"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icons_buscar_32px"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/mBuscar"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/consumosButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:tint="@color/black"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tipsButton"
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Tips"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icons_consejos_32px"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/mTips"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/searchButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:tint="@color/black"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gasolinerasButtonOld"
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:contentDescription="@string/SearchFuelStation"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icons_perfil_32px"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/mPerfil"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tipsButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:tint="@color/black"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Por lo que tengo entendido al usar un constraintlayout debería adaptarse a los distintos tipos de pantalla pero en resoluciones de 800x400px el botón "perfil" no se ve. ¿Que puedo hacer para adaptarlo a cualquier pantalla en la que se ejecute mi app? ¿Debo crear un layout para cada tipo de densidad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Para que tu menú inferior sea compatible para todos los tamaños y densidades, lo recomendable es usar un [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView)**

Primeramente agregas la dependencia necesaria a tu archivo build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   //...
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
}
```

Agregas el `BottomNavigationView` en el layout de tu Activity

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

y dentro de `res/menu/` agrega el menú definiendo sus elementos, bottom_navigation_main.xml :

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_home"
          android:title="@string/home"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_home" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_favs"
          android:title="@string/favs"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_favs" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/menu_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings" />
 </menu>
```

de esta forma obtendrás un menú inferior que se soporte en todos los tamaños y densidades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]